# Is Hemingway's poem entitled MITRAILLIATRICE or MITRAIGLIATRICE?

Tags: poetry, title, ernest-hemingway

I read -- a few months ago -- Hemingway's juvenilia poetry & short-story collection stoically entitled *Three Stories & Ten Poems*. It was published in the early 1920s -- I think 1923, but I've heard 1921 thrown around. Or, perhaps that was the date he wrote it. [If you are interested you can access and download the *Three Stories & Ten Poems* collection for free from Project Gutenburg.](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/59603)

I really enjoyed the poetry. In my opinion, the best poem in the collection is:

> The mills of the gods grind slowly;
>   But this mill
>   Chatters in mechanical staccato.
>   Ugly short infantry of the mind,
>   Advancing over difficult terrain,
>   Make this Corona
>   Their mitrailleuse.

(A "mitrailleuse" is a type of machine-gun: presumably a French one, used during W.W.I.)

I've read online that the poem is entitled "MITRAILLIATRICE". But, Project Guttenburg -- in their version of the collection -- calls the poem "MITRAIGLIATRICE". I have found the following information from [here](http://nwpressbooks.blogspot.com/2008/09/extremely-rare-1923-hemingway-poetry.html?m=1):

> "Mitraigiatrice" (July printing of TSTP) was spelled "Mitrailliatrice" (January printing, Poetry Magazine).

However, I do not know which title is "correct". Does anyone have any information about this?

EDIT: As far as I can tell, the quote above is incorrect. In the Project Guttenburg version of the poem, it is entitled MITRAIGLIATRICE. Presumably "Miltraigiatrice" is a misquote or misspelling of that. I'm amazed I didn't notice that.

Also, what is the meaning(s) of either of the titles? I assumed that it was supposed to be some sort of French play-on-words, but, not knowing French (I had to Google the word "mitrailleuse") I am ignorant. I feel I am missing an integral part of the poem.

Comment: [*mitrailleuse*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mitrailleuse) is French; [*mitraigliatrice*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitragliatrice) is Italian, and *mitrailliatrice* seems like a French-influenced misspelling of the Italian. The two real words mean *machine gun*.

Comment: What exactly is the question being asked here?

Comment: @muru I've edited the question to focus it more. At its root it seems clear; just there was a lot of discussion around which obscured the actual query.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rand al'Thor

Comment: Thanks @Peter Shor That's clearer. It's a reference -- presumably -- to the Italian front where Hemingway was wounded.

Comment: @PeterShor The Italian word is *mitragliatrice* not *mitraigliatrice* :).

Comment: @DenisNardin: thanks for the correction. So both Hemingway's title and the revised title were Fritalian. I don't know whether that was deliberate, or simply a typo.

Comment: This 1923 (signed) edition has the title on the front cover; Mitraigliatrice - https://www.oakknoll.com/resources/bookexcerpts/102275.pdf

Comment: Cool @Valorum I think that Hemingway just mis-named it -- in a mistake. But, it is odd.

EDIT: Thanks for your interest and the new information & evidence. :)

Comment: Any help here; https://books.google.com/books?id=O_m2BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA199&lpg=PA199&dq=%22Mitraigiatrice%22&source=bl&ots=Ww8vT68GZh&sig=ACfU3U158MJOZfE4kCDGHFTkOQEhbGNG4g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiewv747e_nAhVO-6QKHYMrDhoQ6AEwAnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Mitraigiatrice%22&f=false?